# Creating .Net SSRS Scheduler/Subscription App

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We need to develop an SSRS subscription app in .net and I have no experience in this.

I believe I can use the ReportServer API to send schedules (programmatically schedule a report):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/building-applications-using-the-web-service-and-the-net-framework?toc=%2fsql%2freporting-services%2freport-server-web-service%2fnet-framework%2ftoc.json&view=sql-server-2017

The challenging thing I suspect is creating a flexible UI just like in SSRS. Is there a way I can pull up this screen without rebuilding it?
[image]

Anyone that has done this before do you have any tips that could lead me to the right direction? Which API resource did you refer to? Are there any existing libraries I can use?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this question isn't best suited to SO - so will probably get closed. However having done what you are considering I can tell you it totally up to you - SSRS provide the URL for rendering the reports. Everything else is down to your personal choice - there are no shortcuts. Personally I found it quicker to build the interface as a web UI.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks, your response is helpful and so I suppose it is useful to post such a post on SO :). How else can one reach so many people with such a specific need? Btw, how long did it take you to create all that?

Comment: For better or worse SO is about solving specific programming problems, not providing guidance on more discussion based advice. It took many weeks to get a working solution. There is the UI, storing the schedules, the scheduling engine. We also added an SQL based parameter selection i.e. run the report for the results of a specified query. And we added automatic printing of some reports.

Comment: The scheduling engine was built from the ground up as well? You didn't use something like this? https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: No, a scheduling engine isn't that hard - just a windows service with a timer. But hey whatever works :)